# React ref has no value in onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a react component that contains an input with a ref, but I cannot get the value of it.

Here is an example code that shows the problem, together with a jsfiddle link:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  onClick: function () {
    console.log(this.refs.name.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input ref="name" onChange={this.onClick}/>;
  }
});

React.render(<Hello key="world" />, document.body);
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfh2Lx3/1/)

Thx for all help,
J

Comment: Note that the version of React in your fiddle is 0.12. The current version as of posting this question is 0.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to React 0.14, `this.refs.name` is not a DOM element. To access the DOM element, you will need to call [`getDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode):

```
onChange: function () {
  console.log(this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value);
},
```